# SQL clause on search

Tags: c#, sql

I want to find books by title (Cyrillic). I use this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Books 
WHERE Title = 'Заветът на Чърчил'
```

but the result is empty ...

I change my type of val to `nvarchar`, but still get nothing...

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use N before the value when working with nvarchar:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Books WHERE Title = N'Заветът на Чърчил'
```